# How to open the page for an extension inside VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My extension shows a notification about usage data that it collects. There isn't much room in a standard notification for lots of details so I'd like to link to the extension's page on the marketplace. It is possible to open a particular extensions page on the marketplace inside VS Code? Is it possible to link to a particular section?

We can link to the documentation online but we don't want to assume that the user has a active public internet connection, plus, it seems better that we link to the documentation for the currently installed version of the extension rather than latest available online.

The closest that we've found is using a `command:my-extension.my-command` link in the notification text where the command runs:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.extensions.action.showExtensionsWithIds', [
  'my-publisher.my-extension',
]);
```

But that only takes the user to the extensions section with the id pre-entered but then the user has the click on the extension in the left-hand bar and then scroll to the appropriate section.

Comment: the extension page in the extensions bar is the same as the marketplace page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a lot of extensions call the following,

```
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('extension.open', 'ms-python.python'); // open Extension tab and show extension details.
```

Comment: This is what I was after. Thank you. Worth noting it only seems to work when the extension is installed via vsix file (or the marketplace) and not when doing regular extension development.

Answer (score 1):

```
await vscode.env.openExternal(vscode.Uri.parse('vscode:extension/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint'));
```